# Thycotic WebService DownloadFileAttachementByItemId method

Tags: python

A web service is accessible to Thycotic users https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Using-Web-Services-with-Windows-Authentication-PowerShell .

I am able to download the file but i am unable to read the content of the file:

```
file = client.service.DownloadFileAttachmentByItemId(authtoken, secret.SecretSummaries.SecretSummary[0].SecretId,secretvalue.Secret.Items.SecretItem[1].Id)
```

This succeeds and returns:

```
       (FileDownloadResult){
         Errors = ""
         FileAttachment = "YAAiAAJBEqww"
           FileName = "nonesense.txt"
       }
```

if i try to read the file returned

```
         with open(file,'r') as file_handle:
                for line in file_handle:
                  print line
```

I get this error:

```
         TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Answer (score 0):

data = base64.b64decode(file.FileAttachment)